# stm32 UART Receive Data in Interrupt Method

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

Hey friends I am receiving data from PC to `STM32L412` with a fixed size of 4 Bytes. When I am sending 4 bytes to `STM`, it is giving interrupt when the buffer is filled. Suppose if I send a command RLON (which means RED LED ON) and GLON (Green LED ON) then it is working fine, but when I send three bytes the buffer will not fill and then if I send the next 4 Bytes I am getting below issue.

1. RLON ---ok
2. GLON -- OK

   [image: ss]
3. RL (Sending RL)
4. GLON

The above third and fourth case is my issue.

What to do for clearing the UART buffer/UART Data Register
I am also calling RxhalfCallback also

Comment: Please do not show pictures of plain text. Instead copy&paste it as formatted text directly into your question.

Comment: General note: If you cannot ensure that you will always get valid data, you must make the receiver more robust. Instead of waiting for a complete frame, you might need to receive and handle every single byte and decide whether you need to wait for more or discard the current buffer.